# ¿Cómo configuro git para ignorar archivos locales?

Tags: git, gitignore

¿Puedo ignorar los archivos localmente sin utilizar la configuración global de Git? A veces tengo archivos locales o carpetas que quiero ignorar, pero no los quiero incluir en el repositorio utilizando `.gitignore`

*Pregunta original en [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/how-do-i-configure-git-to-ignore-some-files-locally) (inglés)*

Comment: Curiosa pregunta. Cuál sería el caso de uso? Al final el `.gitignore` existe para compartir ignores dentro de un proyecto. Y si los patrones son solamente tuyos siempre se añaden a la configuración global.

Comment: Puedes tener un acceso directo, una carpeta que no pertenece al repositorio o algún fichero temporal que genera algún programa que usas. Siempre es bueno conocerlo

Comment: en esos casos lo normal suele ser tenerlo en el proyecto (si esperas que otra gente lo tenga) o en el global si es solo par ati

Answer (score 5):

De la [documentación de Git](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> Los patrones que son específicos de un repositorio concreto pero que no necesitan ser compartidos con otros repositorios relacionados (por ejemplo, los archivos auxiliares de un repositorio que son específicos del flujo de trabajo de un usuario) deben ir en el archivo `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude`.

El archivo `.git/info/exclude` tiene el mismo formato que cualquier archivo `.gitignore`.

**Otro método sería usar:**

```
git update-index --skip-worktree <file-list>
```

Y para deshacer el comando anterior:

```
git update-index --no-skip-worktree <file-list>
```

Comment: Es bueno el punto, pero esto sirve para archivos a los que _no_ se les ha hecho tracking. Una vez que un archivo ya está _tracked_, agregar al `.gitignore` o a `.git/info/exclude` no hace diferencia. En ese caso se _podría_ utilizar `git update-index --assume-unchanged tal-archivo`.